# Load and random shuffle 8 gigabytes of csv data in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, machine-learning, bigdata

Essentially, I've got 8 gigabytes of CSV data and I want to shuffle it randomly so that I can do mini batches in my ML model. However, if I were to load 8gb of data straight into Python and shuffle it, there seems to have a memory problem.

But, if I load data chunk by chunk then shuffle it, then the data is still in the same pattern since it is sorted originally. This is what I've done so far.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

// get data with size equal to CHUNK_SIZE
reader = pd.read_csv(path , header=0, iterator=True)
data = reader.get_chunk(CHUNK_SIZE)

// randomly shuffle
data = np.random.shuffle(data)
```

Are there any ways that I can do it fast and efficiently? Thank you.

UPDATE: I have approximately 30,000,000 rows and it has been sorted by time.

Comment: GB=Gigabytes, Gb=Gigabits, gb=?

Comment: Just fixed the title. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Please describe the chunking model you refer to. Could you not make a pass over the data with say `awk` and take lines based on a random number for example. So if you wanted 10% of the data, read lines and generate a random number between 0 and 1 for each line and discard it if less than 0.9? Then you don't load the entire file into memory.

Comment: I'm assuming you are not in Linux or do not want to use [shuf](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/shuf-invocation.html). One solution could be to use a database access to file (big code; using for example pytables). A smaller code would probably rely on multiple file reads but it would probably be slow. How many rows (this is what you want to shuffle right?) does your file have? Do you have the same number of characters in each row (making possible the use of seek)?

Comment: @MarkSetchell I have posted an update.

Comment: @armatita Thank you for your help. I'm using Mac OS but it is actually a good idea when using a database access and I'm looking into it now. I have posted an update on the number of rows I have and all rows have the same number of characters.

Comment: Ok, but before looking into the database (I'm guessing it will take some time) check the `shuf` command (`gshuf` in Mac?). You can apparently install coreutils quite easily. [Check this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/142860/install-shuf-on-os-x?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa).

Comment: @armatita gshuf works. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a concept...

Generate 30,000,000 line CSV with Perl - takes 11 seconds on my Mac:

```
perl -E 'for($i=0;$i<30000000;$i++){say "Line $i,field2,field3,",int rand 100}' > BigBoy.csv
```

**Sample Output**

```
Line 0,field2,field3,49
Line 1,field2,field3,6
Line 2,field2,field3,15
...
Line 29999998,field2,field3,79
Line 29999999,field2,field3,19
```

Take 1% of the lines and shuffle them - takes 3 seconds and 15MB of RAM:

```
awk 'rand()>0.99' BigBoy.csv | gshuf > RandomSet.csv
```

`RandomSet.csv` contains 299,748 lines:

**Sample Output**

```
Line 15348259,field2,field3,95
Line 1642442,field2,field3,93
Line 29199452,field2,field3,52
```

---

`gshuf` installed on Mac using **homebrew**:

```
brew install coreutils
```